# SQL query to give a summation of a data value and count number of times it is above 60

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am attempting to query the following data. For each time period, from the PrctBusy column  I am wanting the Max, Min, Avg, total count and the count of times > 60.

```
Array           TimeStamp       Category Instance PrctBusy  QueUtil
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:00    FE_DIR  FA-1E   59      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:00    FE_DIR  FA-1F   9       0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:00    FE_DIR  FA-1G   9       0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:00    FE_DIR  FA-1H   9       0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:00    FE_DIR  FA-2E   64      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:00    FE_DIR  FA-2F   10      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:00    FE_DIR  FA-2G   9       0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:00    FE_DIR  FA-2H   10      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:00    FE_DIR  FA-3E   64      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:00    FE_DIR  FA-3F   9       0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:00    FE_DIR  FA-3G   9       0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:00    FE_DIR  FA-3H   9       0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:00    FE_DIR  FA-4E   64      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:00    FE_DIR  FA-4F   10      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:00    FE_DIR  FA-4G   9       0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:00    FE_DIR  FA-4H   9       0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:05    FE_DIR  FA-1E   62      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:05    FE_DIR  FA-1F   12      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:05    FE_DIR  FA-1G   12      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:05    FE_DIR  FA-1H   12      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:05    FE_DIR  FA-2E   66      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:05    FE_DIR  FA-2F   13      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:05    FE_DIR  FA-2G   12      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:05    FE_DIR  FA-2H   12      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:05    FE_DIR  FA-3E   66      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:05    FE_DIR  FA-3F   12      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:05    FE_DIR  FA-3G   12      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:05    FE_DIR  FA-3H   12      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:05    FE_DIR  FA-4E   66      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:05    FE_DIR  FA-4F   13      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:05    FE_DIR  FA-4G   13      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:05    FE_DIR  FA-4H   11      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:10    FE_DIR  FA-1E   52      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:10    FE_DIR  FA-1F   12      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:10    FE_DIR  FA-1G   12      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:10    FE_DIR  FA-1H   12      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:10    FE_DIR  FA-2E   56      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:10    FE_DIR  FA-2F   13      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:10    FE_DIR  FA-2G   12      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:10    FE_DIR  FA-2H   12      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:10    FE_DIR  FA-3E   56      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:10    FE_DIR  FA-3F   12      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:10    FE_DIR  FA-3G   12      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:10    FE_DIR  FA-3H   12      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:10    FE_DIR  FA-4E   56      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:10    FE_DIR  FA-4F   13      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:10    FE_DIR  FA-4G   13      0
000198701258    2016-07-01 00:10    FE_DIR  FA-4H   11      0
```

I have tried several different Queries,  The one that is the closet to what I want is:

```
SELECT TimeStamp, 
    max(prctbusy) AS maxPrctBusy, 
    min(prctbusy) AS minPrctBusy, 
    AVG(prctbusy) AS avgPrctBusy, 
    count(prctbusy) AS numPrctBusy,  
  ( SELECT count(prctbusy) 
    FROM VMAXPortUtil 
    WHERE array like '%1258%' and Category like '%FE_DIR%' and prctbusy > 60
    ) AS above60 
FROM VMAXPortUtil
WHERE array like '%1258%' and Category like '%FE_DIR%' 
GROUP BY TimeStamp 
Order by TimeStamp
```

Unfortunately the result is not quite correct and giving a total count above 60 instead of by each TimeStamp.

What I am getting:

```
TimeStamp       maxPrctBusy minPrctBusy avgPrctBusy numPrctBusy above60
2016-07-01 00:00    64      9           22          16          8494
2016-07-01 00:05    66      11          25          16          8494
2016-07-01 00:10    56      11          23          16          8494
```

What I Need:

```
TimeStamp       maxPrctBusy minPrctBusy avgPrctBusy numPrctBusy above60
2016-07-01 00:00    64      9           22          16          3
2016-07-01 00:05    66      11          25          16          4
2016-07-01 00:10    56      11          23          16          0
```

I think a union might be what I need and count the number above 60.  but I have not figured out how get the number of result rows the same.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TimeStamp, 
    max(prctbusy) AS maxPrctBusy, 
    min(prctbusy) AS minPrctBusy, 
    AVG(prctbusy) AS avgPrctBusy, 
    count(prctbusy) AS numPrctBusy,
    sum(case when prctbusy > 60 then 1 else 0 end) AS above60
FROM VMAXPortUtil
WHERE array like '%1258%' and Category like '%FE_DIR%' 
GROUP BY TimeStamp 
Order by TimeStamp
```

This should do the trick assuming you want numPrctBusy to remain.

You can add non group fields inside aggregate functions allowing you to do a comparison check